# How to select string from an array of strings or a csv?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to create a website for a club which displays the relation between to items from a drop-down-menu. As example we take rock-paper-scissors.
The data would be given by a .csv file, as an example the following .csv:

```
;           Stone;                      Scissors;                   Paper
Stone;      Nothing happens.;           Scissors get scattered.;    Paper wraps stone.
Scissors;   Stone scatters Scissors.;   Nothing happens.;           Paper gets cut.
Paper;      Stone gets wrapped.;        Scissors cut Paper.;        Nothing happens.
```

I need to read the .csv and generate the select statements (first one for first row, second one for first column), which would end up like this (2x):

```
<b>Your Choice:</b>
<select id="yours" onchange="battle()">
<option style="display:none" disabled selected value> -- select an option -- 
</option>
<option>Stone</option>
<option>Scissors</option>
<option>Paper</option>
</select>
```

To this point, I got all this running in .php (read the csv, generate dropdowns).

Now comes the point where I am unsure about the proper, web-dev way of doing things:
1. How to store the table whithin the output of the pho script, so I can access it cleanly using js?
2. How to get the values from said table?

Pseudocode-solution:

```
<script>

<my clean array data>

function battle() {
  var x = document.getElementById("yours").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("opponent").value;
  var result = array.select(mine = x, opponent = y)
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a javascript object with your table values would be a simple way to solve this.

In php, you want to have an array with this structure, generated from your CSV file, you probably already have this or something similar:

```
$a = [
    "Stone" => [
        "Stone" => "Nothing Happens.",
        "Scissors" => "Scissors get scattered (shattered?).",
        "Paper" => "Paper wraps stone."
    ],
    // ... "Scissors" and "Paper" go here
];
```

Then you need to write out a line of javascript encoding the php array into a javascript object:

```
<script>
var resultsTable = <?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;
</script>
```

Then your battle function becomes:

```
function battle() {
  var x = document.getElementById("yours").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("opponent").value;
  var result = resultsTable[x][y];
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```